# Android Lollipop bitmap not drawing on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-custom-view

I use this custom view > http://pastebin.com/fi1KaRbR.
When I returned on fragment in which situated this view sometimes it is not drawing. I noticed that problem only for android 5(I have tested on emulator: on nexus5 api19 and nexus4 api19 everything work fine, but on nexus4 api22 and nexus5 api22 sometimes it is not drawn).